# How to create multiple share targets for Image sharing?

Tags: android

I would like to have multiple share options when we try to share an image.Similar to how instagram is doing in the shared image.

[image: Multiple Share Options]

I could not find proper documentation on how to do it.
Thanks

Comment: you have to provide different intent names for each. like "com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY" for story.

Comment: Can u point me to a doc or some example please

Comment: https://gist.github.com/michaeltys/a8613e5aea9db8e4684bf85568e40160

Comment: or go to below link shareimage function
https://www.androidcode.ninja/android-share-intent-example/

Comment: I don't have to share , i have to make my app share target so that when u select images in ur gallery and try to share , my app comes with few possible options

Comment: you have to create intent filter for particular Activity in Manifest file and in that Activity you have to getIntent(). for detail info kindly go through this link : https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/sharing/receive.html

Comment: Is it not possible to have multiple share target for same activity?With this approach i will have to redirect user to two different activity but our app is single activity based app

Answer (score 2):

We can add intent-filter to different activities in manifest to create multiple share target.

```
<activity
    android:name="mobi.abc.xyz.FirstActivity">

    <intent-filter android:label="@string/socials">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name="mobi.abc.xyz.SecondActivity">

    <intent-filter android:label="@string/share_image_to_edit">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Also, don't use hard-coded string for label , or else it will not work in google photos.